# How to get access token and make salesforce rest api requests with paw?

Tags: salesforce, paw-app

Salesforce OAuth request is in the form:

```sh
$ curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token \
    -d "grant_type=password" \
    -d "client_id=myclientid" \
    -d "client_secret=myclientsecret" \
    -d "username=mylogin@salesforce.com" \
    -d "password=mypassword123456"
```

It's unclear how to enter these params in paw OAuth v2 dialog box...

Further Reading in [Set Up Authorization > Session ID Authorization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

Comment: not helpful in this precise case, but there's a nice blog article from Salesforce about using Paw for testing their API https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/using-paw-work-salesforce-rest-apis.html

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like these parameters are expected to be sent in the request body as Form URL-Encoded (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). For that you need to go to the Body tab and pick the "Form URL-Encoded" mode.

[image: Form URL-Encoded HTTP POST Request in Paw]

I don't have the right Salesforce credentials to test myself, but it should be working.

Here's a Pawprint (shared snippet) of what your request looks like (you can hit "Open in Paw" on the webpage below to get the configuration of the above screenshot):
https://paw.pt/azxQAGn2

Comment: Micha, tks, that is very helpful! :-)
Now, that I am able to fetch an access-token, the really helpful part would be to take it automatically to authenticate subsequent requests, as depicted in the last paragraph here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm